# How to disable Reference.cs file to pop-up each time an exception is caught while debugging WCF?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I am building a system and using WCF services. Each time there is an exception caught it stops the program from executing (clearly) and then opens Reference.cs file in my VS2010. I find nothing useful about it currently, as it always points to one place in this file. Thus, my question is - is it possible in VS2010 to set the file (Reference.cs) to not show up at exception and if so, where?

Googled it, but without luck..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sergy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22789696/80274) is close, but there is one more component you will likely need to do. In the settings you also need to check the box for "Enable Just My Code".

[image]

What this will do is any function that has the attribute [`GeneratedCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.codedom.compiler.generatedcodeattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (which all of the functions inside `Refrence.cs` will have) will be skipped over by the debugger and any exception thrown from inside a function marked as GeneratedCode will go up the call stack till it hits a function that is considered "user code".

Answer (score 2):

You can disable execution break when exception was thrown by opening `Debug -> Exceptions...` dialog and disabling each check box in the `Thrown` column.

I would not recommend to disable check boxes in the `User-unhandled` column; in general, all exceptions in your application should be catched and handled carefully. Set it something like the image below:

[image: The exception settings window]